# scroll view in table view cell won't show correctly images and there is one extra page in paging mode in swift 4

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, swift4, scroll-paging

I used scroll view with images in table view cell But there are two problems :
1- there is an extra page not the count of my images and 
2: the image doesn't fill the screen and there are white space between each image [image: here is the image of what I see]

and here is my table view cell with scroll view codes

```
class scrollViewCell: UITableViewCell , UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var contentWidth : CGFloat = 0.0


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()        

    scrollView.delegate = self
    for image in 0...2 {
        let imageToDisplay = UIImage(named : "1")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image : imageToDisplay)

        let xCoordinate = self.contentView.frame.midX + self.contentView.frame.width * CGFloat(image)
        contentWidth += self.contentView.frame.width
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xCoordinate - 50 , y: 0 , width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: 100)

        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // OR .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true


    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: self.contentView.frame.height)


}


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / CGFloat(414))
}


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Comment: you want the image to fill the cell completely in width and height ???

Comment: yes I want to image fill the cell equal width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
func addscrollV()
{
     for image in 0...2 {
    let imageToDisplay = UIImage(named : "1")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image : imageToDisplay)

    let xCoordinate = self.contentView.frame.width * CGFloat(image)
    contentWidth += self.contentView.frame.width
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xCoordinate , y: 0 , width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
   }

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: self.contentView.frame.height)

}

func layoutSubviews()
{
  super.layoutSubviews()
   if(Once)
   {
     Once = false
     self.addscrollV()
  }
}
```

Comment: ok that's worked thanks But page indicators won't change how can I fix that ?

Comment: Once (declare it as a bool var ) used as layoutSubviews method is called multiple times , check if page circle color matches with the image's color

Comment: sorry But I didn't get what you mean can you tell me by codes please ?

Answer (score 0):

Issues is in your xCoordinate calculation, the contentView frame wont be available in awakeFromNib.

You should not user `super.awakeFromNib` to calculate the frames.
create a method called

`func configureUI(){
   //Update your UI here
}`

Call this method from `cellForRowAtIndex:` delegate method of UITableViewCell

Comment: I used that But again there is extra space at the first image

Comment: use `imageview.frame.size.width` in your xCoordinate calculation

Comment: I used that and if I use that I can't see any images